# Регулярка для NOTEPAD++

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Здравствуйте . В notepad есть строка

```
    28872 => Array
        (
            84 => /md_function.php
        )

    938483 => Array
        (
            14 => error_reporting
        )
```

подскажите регулярку для добавления кавычек в значения массива, чтобы я получил на выходе

```
28872 => Array
    (
        84 => "/md_function.php"
    )

938483 => Array
    (
        14 => "error_reporting"
    )
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строка поиска

```
(?:=>\s+)(?!Array)(.+)$
```

меняем на `=> "\1"`

[Пример с описанием](https://regex101.com/r/bS4eC6/2)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но Notepad не находит данное рег.выражение

Comment: сходил, проверил, поименял :)

Comment: все ровно  данное рег.выражение не находит ничего ..=( Возможно вы неправильно поняли вопрос , т.к у вас используются некоторые символы в регулярке, которые в описании к NotePad не видел

Comment: смотрим перехватку экрана - http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=50a5d1acbd970a7f73366ed2679ea4b7

Comment: ну странно как-то . Не хочет работать )) - http://s017.radikal.ru/i401/1603/60/23fde7de5f01.png

Comment: возможно дело в версии, у меня 6.7.8.2

Comment: да, обновил и все окей .Спасибо!

Comment: рад был помочь!